# magento 2 product page gallery images not showing

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, gallery-image

I am facing issue with gallery images I have images in backend but not showing in front-end product page gallery slider I have checked there is no error in the console.

Comment: did you migrate OR upgrade ?

Comment: What is solution you followed?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to run these commands on the root of the project:**

> php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> chmod 777 -R

**Thanks.**

Comment: I have done all these